# Is it possible to use NSThreads for parsing four different URLs using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsthread

If I try to parse single HTTP URL, it will be done quickly. But if I have to parse four different URLs at application launch, is it feasible to use NSThreads and NSOperation queue.
Can any one explain with a small example if possible?

Sagos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an NSOperation subclass, and in the main method, do something like this:

```
- (void)main
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL_] autorelease];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

Implement your parser delegate methods on your NSOperation subclass. Then instantiate the subclasses, assign them the URLS, and add them to an operation queue. Use notifications or delegates to know when they are finished.

Comment: Actually I have four different URLs, each one of them parses the XML document separately, and store the value in the database. I implement the parser delegate methods on individual URL call. It would be great if you can help me with some examples on above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Do you have 4 xml files that need to be parsed in different ways (i.e. they all have a different structure)? Or 4 files containing different data but with the same structure?

Comment: 4 files containing different data but with the same structure but each one of them is stored in different arrays.

Comment: Then just add a property or initializer to set the URL (the myURL_ variable in the example above) and create four operations, setting their URLs to the four files you need.

Comment: You mean create four different NSOperations for each URL?

Comment: No, create one operation for each URL, unless you need to parse the same url 4 times.

Comment: If I am not wrong this is what you mean:NSString * url1 =@"http://www.apple.com/";NSString * url2=   @"http://www.google.com/"; NSString * url3 =@"http://abc.com/";
Url1DownloaderOperation * operation1 =[UrlDownloader1Operation urlDownloaderWithUrlString:url1];[_queue addOperation:operation1];
Url2DownloaderOperation * operation2 =        [UrlDownloader2Operation urlDownloaderWithUrlString:url2];
[_queue addOperation:operation2];
Url3DownloaderOperation * operation3 =           [UrlDownloader3Operation urlDownloaderWithUrlString:url3];
[_queue addOperation:operation3];

Comment: If the files are the same structure, then you don't need to create a different subclass for each url - just four instances, as you've shown.

Comment: Whats "If the files are the same structure" ?? I have different URLs as shown and data in each URL is different.

Comment: Well, if the files conform to the same XML structure. As in the same parsing code will parse all four. As you said you have "4 files containing different data but with the same structure". So I'm assuming this is the case. If you need different code to parse each one, then different subclasses could work.

Comment: Ok got that!!!!  Thanks a lot for your patience and help. Will have to create different subclasses for each URL but my only concern would be then timing issues and memory consumption.

Comment: Do they have to parsed in a particular order? If so, create one, then in the callbacks you write to indicate it's finished, create another, and so on. If order isn't important, but having so many operations going at once consumes too much memory, reduce the number of allowed operations at once in your queue.

Comment: But then I am again back to the same scenario where using NSXMLParser which will parse the first URL and store the data and then the second. SO will there be any difference in NSOperation that will help me to parse synchronously to save time.

Comment: You mentioned timing was a problem which I took to imply that order could be critical. If it is, then there's not much you can do but wait for the network to get your data. But if order isn't critical, just add your operations to your queue. It will fire them all off asynchronously and you will absolutely save time. If memory is a problem, there are other ways you can optimize that, such as using NSURLConnectionDelegate and incrementally writing your data to files on disk, and then parsing them (much quicker than networking) by file one at a time. But that is out of the scope of this comment.

Comment: I guess order is not that important. I will have to add all of them into the operations, which will fire asynchronously and hope to reduce the wait for the network to get the data like I have mentioned in my example above.

Comment: Hey carl thanks for pointing me to the new direction of using NSURLConnectionDelegate. It surely reduces the memory consumption and helps me to parse the data very fast. But have a quick other question I have used the logic from SeismicXML from Apple store and used to parse the data. But my new concern is whenever I do build and debug the code, it runs fine. but when I run the application on its own it does not work. Do you have any idea why it wont work when I run it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do use NSOperationQueue. The following link basically shows how to parse multiple URL (xml files) using NSOperationQueue.

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/275115-nsoperationqueue-for-nsxmlparser-object.html